# How to use the BFS algorithm to keep only the outer points?

Tags: c++, algorithm, path-finding, breadth-first-search

Let's say I have a 500x500 2D grid (from -250 to 250).

Each cell of the grid has a certain value, from 0 to 100.

What I've been trying to do is keep a list of all the cell with a value lower than 50 starting at the point (0, 0), but I would like not to keep all the points, but only the outer points (perimeter, bounds, a cell with a value lower than 50 that does not have 4 adjacent cells with a value lower than 50).

The way I implemented the algorithm, I keep a list of all the points. How should I modify it? I would like to optimize the code if possible (I can have bigger grids), so I would prefer not to iterate again.

```
pointList pointsWithValueBelow50; // The list of points with a value below 50
map<point, bool> pointDiscovered; // A map of the points we already passed through
point a = {0,0};
point b;
int value;
Queue q;

q.enqueue(a);
pointDiscovered[a] = true;
while(!q.isEmpty())
{
    a = q.dequeue(a)
    value = calculateValue(a); // Random method that verify if the points has a value below 50 in the grid
    if (value < 50)
    {
         pointsWithValueBelow50.add(a);
         b[0] = a[0]+1;
         b[1] = a[1];
         if(pointDiscovered[b] == false)
         {
             q.enqueue(b)
             pointDiscovered[b] = true;
         }
         b[0] = a[0]-1;
         b[1] = a[1];
         if(pointDiscovered[b] == false)
         {
             q.enqueue(b)
             pointDiscovered[b] = true;
         }
         b[0] = a[0];
         b[1] = a[1]+1;
         if(pointDiscovered[b] == false)
         {
             q.enqueue(b)
             pointDiscovered[b] = true;
         }
         b[0] = a[0];
         b[1] = a[1]-1;
         if(pointDiscovered[b] == false)
         {
             q.enqueue(b)
             pointDiscovered[b] = true;
         }
    }     
}
```

As you can see, I keep in my list all the points with a value below 50, instead of the outer points. How can I modify this code? Should I use another algorithm?

Comment: So you like to only keep a list of the perimeter points and optimize the algorithm?  Is that what you are saying?  And will there still be a list of the all the points with a value lower than 50?

Comment: what types are `point` and `pointList` ? What does BFS stand for?

Comment: Yeah, I would like a list of all the perimeter points with values below 50 while optimizing the algorithm. I would also like to keep the list with all the points below 50 for other purpose.

Comment: I'm using vtk library, so they have their own container. 'pointlist' is just a list of points (double, double), and 'point' is also 2 double. BFS stands for breadth-first search.

Comment: If you had a 3x3 grid consisting of `[ 0 100 0; 100 0 100; 0 100 0]`, the `0` in the center would be considered an outer point by your definition: "a cell with a value lower than 50 that does not have 4 adjacent cells with a value lower than 50." Does this fit with your intentions?

Comment: Exactly. It's a bit like the flood-filling algorithm where any values higher than 50 act like a wall. But I don't want to fill every cells, only the ones at the border. In your example, 0 is a border since at least one of its adjacent cell has a value higher than 50

Comment: The problem is that your upper and lower bound may lead to and end of path without reaching destination.  If you want to avoid exploring all the possibilites, you could consider using [A* search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A*_search_algorithm)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us consider the cell array as a grey-scale image (where cell values are pixel intensities). What you are attempting to do ("find borders") is a common problem in graphics, and there is a well-known algorithm ([Marching Squares](http://Marching%20Squares)) to find such borders as lists (with the additional property of the lists being ordered, so that when you traverse the list, you are going around the vertexes of a polygon that contains the interesting area.

Marching squares is O(cells) (it only needs to look at each cell-neighbourhood once in the worst case), and can be parallelized for even greater performance. There are many variations, based on what is considered a relevant transition and whether you want to find only *one* boundary or *all* boundaries.

There are many implementations out there. One of the cleanest that I have read is [here](https://github.com/e-ucm/ead/blob/master/engine/core/src/main/java/es/eucm/ead/engine/utils/MarchingSquares.java) (LGPL; returns all boundaries; configurable threshold) - translating it from Java to C++ should be relatively straightforward.

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I was looking for. Do you know if there is an important difference in term of calculation speed between having an unorganized set of points using BSF algorithm and then applying a delaunay surface reconstruction, or using a marching square with the advantage of having a set of organized points?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I forgot to add my solution to the problem. Unfortunately, I think it's memory heavy, so any new answers will be glady accepted!

```
pointList pointsWithValueBelow50; // The list of points with a value below 50
pointList pointsBorder;
map<point, bool> pointDiscovered; // A map of the points we already passed through
map<point, bool> pointVisible; // The final visible points
map<point, point> pointParent; // A map of the parent point
point a = {0,0};
point b;
int value;
Queue q;

q.enqueue(a);
pointDiscovered[a] = true;
while(!q.isEmpty())
{
    a = q.dequeue(a)
    value = calculateValue(a); // Random method that verify if the points has a value below 50 in the grid
    if (value < 50)
    {
         pointsWithValueBelow50.add(a);
         b[0] = a[0]+1;
         b[1] = a[1];
         if(pointDiscovered[b] == false)
         {
             q.enqueue(b)
             pointParent[b] = a
             pointDiscovered[b] = true;
         }
         b[0] = a[0]-1;
         b[1] = a[1];
         if(pointDiscovered[b] == false)
         {
             q.enqueue(b)
             pointParent[b] = a
             pointDiscovered[b] = true;
         }
         b[0] = a[0];
         b[1] = a[1]+1;
         if(pointDiscovered[b] == false)
         {
             q.enqueue(b)
             pointParent[b] = a
             pointDiscovered[b] = true;
         }
         b[0] = a[0];
         b[1] = a[1]-1;
         if(pointDiscovered[b] == false)
         {
             q.enqueue(b)
             pointParent[b] = a
             pointDiscovered[b] = true;
         }
    }
    else     
    {
        if(pointVisible[pointParent[a]] == false)
        {
            pointVisible[pointParent[a]] = true;
            pointsBorder.add(poinParent[a]);
        }
    }
}
```

the idea is simply that if I'm at a point that has a value higher than 50, we let the parent point know that he has to be visible since he is  "border" point.