# Sort List of Adjacent Points into Polygon

Tags: c++, geometry, polygon

I have a list of points (x, y) that represent the outline of a polygon and are not in any specific order (for example, if we have the rectangle ABCD, the list of points could be something like DACB). In the attached image, the blue shape is the polygon, the points in the list are black and the red line is what correct order of the points should be when sorted.
[image: Polygon Outline]

So, the question is, how could I go about sorting this list into one that represents the outline of the polygon in clockwise or counterclockwise order?

Comment: Definitely nontrivial. Look for computational geometry, it's my best advice (admittedly not that much...)

Comment: Your sample is inconsistent: The outline of the middle/right corner is rectangular

Comment: Have you tried using marching square algorithm? You can find all border points in order using it

Comment: Dieter Lücking, my bad, fixed it now.

Comment: asdfasdf, I'm not familiar with that algorithm. Got any links to sites that explain it? Or perhaps do it here if it's not too long and complicated?

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no easy way to do it, I had almost the exact same question as you some weeks ago, and a guy showed me that algorithm : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30762951/how-to-use-the-bfs-algorithm-to-keep-only-the-outer-points

Here is the example of marching square algorithm he showed me : 

https://github.com/e-ucm/ead/blob/master/engine/core/src/main/java/es/eucm/ead/engine/utils/MarchingSquares.java

Comment: To make it short, you define a primary area as a 2d array (in your example all your blue and black square), and another smaller area, a 2x2 square, that will "march" around your primary area. Depending on the state of the 2x2 square, it will go a direction or another, going around any surface in counterclockwise direction. Here is an illustration of what I'm saying : http://www.sakri.net/blog/2009/05/28/detecting-edge-pixels-with-marching-squares-algorithm/

Comment: Alright then, I'll take a shot at it first thing tomorrow morning and we'll see where it gets me. Thanks.